# How to increase List bullet size in itext android?

Tags: android, itext

I am using itext pdf generater inside my android application. Where I am using both Ordered list and unOrdered List. I am unable to increase size of bullets and Order's text. I have increased List Item size using below code.

```
  List list = new List(List.ORDERED);
    list.setPostSymbol(") ");
    //Ingredients Entry
    for (String ingredient : ingredients.split("#")) {

        font = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, txtSize_content, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);
        chunk = new Chunk(ingredient, font);
        //To set alignment to chunk
        phrase = new Phrase();
        phrase.add(chunk);
        para = new Paragraph();
        para.add(phrase);
        para.setSpacingBefore(txtSize_content);
        para.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
        //end To set alignment to chunk
        //Add List Item to List
        ListItem item = new ListItem(para);
        item.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED);
        list.add(item);

    }
    document.add(list);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are messing things up with that chunk and phrase combination. Try this instead:

```
list.add(new ListItem(ingredient, font))
```

or create your paragraphs like:

```
new Paragraph(ingredient, font)
```

On unordered lists the first ListItem with a font seems to set the size of all list symbols.
Ordered lists take the font of each ListItem (or paragraph) to render the numbers.
(v4.1.6)

Comment: Perfect solution.